# Gparted shows too high amount of used space of HDD

Tags: hard-drive, gparted

I found some similiar thread, but nothing that answers my question.

Gparted shows that 2,47 TB of my HDD is used although nautilus shows that the data only consumes 1,3 TB. I cannot find a reason for the difference.

```
$ sudo ls -lh /media/simon/Intern_4TB
total 1,3T
drwx------ 2 simon simon  16K Jun 28  2021 lost+found
-rw------- 1 simon simon 330K Feb  1  2022 ncp-config_20220201.tar
-rwxrwxr-x 1 simon simon 330K Jun 25 18:09 ncp-config_20220307.tar
-rw------- 1 simon simon 330K Sep 11 20:10 ncp-config_20220911.tar
-rw-r----- 1 simon simon 638G Jun 25 14:43 nextcloud-bkp_20220615_1655310051.tar
-rw-r----- 1 simon simon 680G Sep 22 07:53 nextcloud-bkp_20220922_1663815603.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 simon simon  11G Feb  5  2022 OpenHAB-2022-02-05.tar.gz
simon@simon-sff:~$ sudo ls -lh /media/simon/Intern_4TB/lost+found
total 0

$ sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
*....I shortened this part as I use ZFS and there is a long list.*
sda      8:0    0 238,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0   238G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0   3,7T  0 disk /media/simon/Intern_4TB
...
```

[Gparted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcIVE.png)

Comment: check dotfiles, `ls -altrh /folder`

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?